# Proof of logical equivalence $(p\rightarrow q)\wedge(q\rightarrow r)\Leftrightarrow p\rightarrow (q\wedge r)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the standard logical equivalence:
$(p\rightarrow q)\wedge(q\rightarrow r)\Leftrightarrow p\rightarrow (q\wedge r)$.

Using several distributive laws I was able to get it down to:
$(\neg p\wedge\neg q) \vee (\neg p\wedge r) \vee  (q\wedge r)$.

I must be missing some manipulation I can do to reduce this.

Comment: Where did you start, where were you trying to get? "Get it down"... get *what* down?

Comment: Well first I got rid of the conditionals by the definition of implication and then I was left with the two compound disjunctive statements with the "and" separating them. I then used distributive law twice and got to the point I stated above. What I meant by get down was that I was trying to get the compound proposition into a form so that I could conclude it was equivalent to the right side.

Comment: How about a truth table? That would be the simplest thing to do, I think.

Comment: Well I could and I have but the point is more to use logical equivalences.

Comment: I haven't worked through the details, but it strikes me that this statement is not correct. Change the bidirectional implication to a simple implication, and it holds, however.

Comment: @Noldorin: Yes, they are not equivalent. See my answer.

Comment: It seems clear to me that it should have been $(p\rightarrow q)\wedge (p\rightarrow r)$ on the right hand side. I checked to make sure it wasn't me who introduced the mistake when I edited the question, and it was incorrect in the original.

Comment: on second thought, for equlivalance your question should be 
$[(p\Rightarrow q)\wedge(q\Rightarrow r)\Leftrightarrow p]\Rightarrow (q\wedge r)$

Answer (score 7):

Umm... maybe I am missing something, but

if $p$ is false, $q$ is true and $r$ is false, then we have that

$(p\rightarrow q)\wedge(q\rightarrow r)$ is false

$p\rightarrow (q\wedge r)$ is true.

So I don't see how you can prove the equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}\hline p&q&r&p\Rightarrow q&q\Rightarrow r&(p\Rightarrow q)\land (q\Rightarrow r)&q\land r&p\Rightarrow(q\land r)&\cdots\\\hline T&T&T&T&T&T&T&T\\T&T&F&T&F&F&F&F\\T&F&T&F&T&F&F&F\\T&F&F&F&T&F&F&F\\F&T&T&T&T&T&T&T\\F&T&F&T&F&F&F&T\\F&F&T&T&T&T&F&T\\F&F&F&T&T&T&F&T\\\hline \end{array}$$

$$ \begin{array}{c|c|c|}\hline \cdots&\big[(p\Rightarrow q)\land (q\Rightarrow r)\big]\iff \big[ p\Rightarrow(q\land r)\big]\\\hline &T\\&T\\&T\\&T\\&F\\&T\\&T\\\hline \end{array}$$